# Observing increased latency in api response after migration to httpClient 5

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am running a performance test on some of my api's which runs 25 threads in parallel for 300 secs.

With HttpClient 4.x the average response time ~300ms
With all resources and environment same and HttpClient 5.X the average response time ~900ms

I took a threadDump and Observed that with HttpClient 4.x i see all 25 threads in Runnable state at a time,
but the same threadDump of HttpClient 5.x shows ~10 threads in Runnable state and rest ~15 in TIMED_WAIT state :

```
http-nio-8087-exec-3" #30 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=687.50ms elapsed=250.17s tid=0x00000276c0ccced0 nid=0x57ec in Object.wait()  [0x000000db766f8000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@17.0.5/Native Method)
waiting on <no object reference available>
at org.apache.hc.core5.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:101)
locked <0x000000060ed18060> (a org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool$1)
at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool$1.get(StrictConnPool.java:184)
locked <0x000000060ed18060> (a org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool$1)
at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool$1.get(StrictConnPool.java:178)
at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$3.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:312)
locked <0x000000060ed180f0> (a org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$3) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.acquireEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:109) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:125)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$$Lambda$2730/0x00000008019530b0.proceed(Unknown Source)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$$Lambda$2730/0x00000008019530b0.proceed(Unknown Source)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$$Lambda$2730/0x00000008019530b0.proceed(Unknown Source)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
```

My Questions:

1. With all resources and environment same with 25 parallel threads why with HttpClient 4.x are Runnable
   and with HttpClient 5.x show only ~10 odd runnable and rest in TIME_WAIT state.
2. Though i did not initialized a async requests why i see a BasicFuture in the TIMED_WAIT thread in httpClient 5 stack trace?

Comment: Could you please share the complete errors in code format? It would make it easier for others to help you with your question.